# I'm trying to run a script but it just says 'error bot not defined'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to build a discord bot but every time I try to run it it just says this `'error bot not defined'` and I'm not sure what causes it as I've defined in in a file I've called bot. The first string of code is the one which vs is having a problem with the second one is the 'bot' file.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.load_extension(help_cog(bot))
    await bot.load_extension(music_cog(bot))

class help_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.help_message = '''
```

General Commands:
/help - displays all the available commands to help all of you Blookteers
/p  - finds a song that you (the blooketeers) have chosen and will play it in your current channel
/q - displays the current music queue chosen by the Blooketeers themselfs
/skip - skips the current song being played which was chosen by one of the Blooketeers
/clear - Stop the music and clears the whole queue
/leave - When the blooketeers are tired of music this command will ofrce the bot to leave the current voice channel
/pause - pauses the current song or resumes if it's aleady paused
/resume - resumes playing the current song

```
'''       
        self.text_channel_text = []
        async def on_ready(self):
            for guild in self.bot.guilds:
                for channel in guild.text_channels:
                     self.text_channel_text.append(channel)

                await self.send_to_all(self.help_message)

        async def send_to_all(self, msg):
            for text_channel in self.text_channel_text:
                await text_channel.send(msg)

    @command.command(name='help', help='Displays all the avalable commands to help out all of you blooketeers!')
    async def help(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.help_message)
```

```
import hikari
import lightbulb
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from help_cog import help_cog 
from music_cog import music_cog

intents=discord.Intents.all()

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = lightbulb.BotApp(token=TOKEN, intents=intents, prefix="!")
bot.remove_command('help')

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
    await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

bot.run()
```

I've tried to change the bot value but everything I've tried has failed as well as trying to use discord.bot instead of lightbulb but I may of done either of these wrong so don't rule them out.

Comment: The file (.py module) that is giving you the error (where you run `@bot.command` I mean) ... Does it know what `"bot"` is? Is there a... `from bot import bot` or... `import bot` (something along those lines) in there?

Comment: You seem to be doing cogs the complete wrong way. Have a look at the docs and see how it works. The migration guide has a short example of how to work with cogs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Comment: The ```   async def setup(bot):
        await bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
        await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot)) ``` looks fine unless you're talking about something else in that case I'm just dumb. @stijndcl

Comment: The `setup` function is supposed to be in your cog's file, not your main file. Commands in your cog use `@commands.command` as the decorator, not `@bot.command`. Extensions should be loaded using `load_extension`, not by importing the cogs in your main file.

Comment: I've updated the code using your information but it's still giving me the same error message so I edited it so it says the whole cog maybe I implamented it wrong, either way it's still not working. @stijndcl

Comment: Can you update your post with the actual traceback of the error so we can see where it came from? Because nothing in your code uses an undeclared "bot" variable anymore. Also your `setup` is still wrong, you should have one setup per cog file, and only load that specific cog. Your `help_cog`'s file shouldn't be adding your `music_cog`, and your `main` doesn't need a `setup` at all (it won't even run).